# How to make multiple payments using a token created from a customer using stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm getting an error when making a charge using a token created from a customer previously created using stripe. I need to be able to charge a user more than once so charges can go to multiple destinations, which is why I'm creating the token. However, when trying to charge anyone using the following code I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'No such token: tok_187sfmBqiK1u6WYC3qS20eNu'

`$stripe_id` and other variables have been assigned in my code, I'm just copy/pasting the main bits:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_mykey-changedforsecurity");   // authorises secret key


$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];


$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "description" => "test customer",
  "source" => $token // obtained with Stripe.js
));


$chargetoken = \Stripe\Token::create(
  array("customer" => $customer->id),
  array("stripe_account" => $stripe_id) // id of the connected account
);


 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $price, 
    "currency" => "gbp", 
    "source" => $chargetoken, 
    "description" => $title, 
    "application_fee" => 20, 
    "destination" => $stripe_id
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

In stripe, any token you got/create is one time so you can not use token twice. 
Stripe supports the charges in 3 ways.

1. Using card token
2. Using token (you are doing)
3. Using customer Id

So in your case simply use customer Id instead of the token to charge a customer multiple time. CustomerId will not expire.

So inside charge object use "customer" field

you can see the charge object here [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#charge_object)